# AWS SAM Local access service on host from Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I am testing a Lambda function using SAM Local.  The function calls out to a REST API.  Locally I have a mock rest service for testing the call.  To connect I am currently using the IP address of the host within the Lambda function.  This works until my IP changes or someone else tries to run the function.  I would like to pass the hostname/ip address to the Lambda function using an environment variable.  This should be quite easy to do once deployed but I haven't found a nice way to set this up in my local template.  Is there a nice way to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

In the template.yml file you can write something like this (see Environment section)

```
LogicFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: function-name
      Handler: src/handlers/index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Environment:
        Variables:
          VAR_ENVIRONMENT: value
      Events:
        # Server
        GetServiceRunningAPI:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /api/ping
            Method: GET
```